# Can I pass time limits as an array for the Between () function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a rather large query with multiple joins and each join has a time range criteria that I'm currently inputting as

```
 between to_date('06/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('09/30/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I would like to make the query more dynamic by grabbing the start and end time limits from

```
SELECT MAX(First) TRI_START, MAX(Last) TRI_END
FROM(
     SELECT
       ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, -3) AS First,
       (ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, +1))-1  AS Last
     FROM ACCOUNT_11
     GROUP BY ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, -3),(ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, +1))-1
     )
```

I was wondering if I could leverage the above across the query?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks :)

Sample query:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.B, T3.C,... COUNT(DISTINCT(T3.X)), COUNT(DISTINCT(T4.Y)),..
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.w = T2.w
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.o = T2.o AND TRUNC(T3.SAMPLE_DATE) between to_date('06/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date('09/30/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
....
....
WHERE T1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR = (SELECT MAX(TRIMESTER_INDICATOR) TRI_IND
                                 FROM(
                                    SELECT TRIMESTER_INDICATOR
                                    FROM ACCOUNT_11
                                    GROUP BY TRIMESTER_INDICATOR
                                    )
                                 )
GROUP BY T1.A, T2.B, T3.C,...
```

I used the CTE and then tried plugging in something like

```
AND TRUNC(T3.SAMPLE_DATE) between dates.TRI_START AND dates.TRI_END
```

But it's throwing an invalid identifier error. I'm not sure how to reference the dates correctly.
Edit: This works great now!! Thanks

PS: I apologize for my inexperience in making edits to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE:

```
with dates as (
      SELECT MAX(First) TRI_START, MAX(Last) TRI_END
      FROM (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, -3) AS First,
                   (ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, +1))-1  AS Last
            FROM ACCOUNT_11
            GROUP BY ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, -3),(ADD_MONTHS(W1.TRIMESTER_INDICATOR, +1))-1
           )
    )
select . . .
from . . . cross join
     dates d
. . .
```

You can then use the dates in the query.  If you need them in a subquery, then you can add another `cross join`.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the prompt response! While I get the concept, I'm unclear about the syntax.. tried doing some quick research online but to no avail. Would you be able to help, if possible? So the structure of my query is as follows:  >select...   >from t1   >left join t2 on   >left join t3 on t2.a=t3.b and t3.sample_date between(..)  > and so on

Comment: @flipflop99 . . . Edit your question with a small sample query.

Comment: I just did. Thanks for your help :)